# How to make a cat/tac stream at given line/second rate?

Tags: linux, shell

imagine you have a big logfile named "filename"

if you **tail -f filename** then you have a stream only if filename updates itself

if you **cat filename** then you have a stream, but cannot read it if you CPU is 
newer than intel 8088

if you **cat filename | more** then you have a stream, page by page, and will probably break your space key

How can i list a file at a given rate (ex: 1 line each 0.05 second) so i have time to read, but i don't need to press space key hundreds of time ?

(i don't use **| grep** because in my particuliar case, i don't know exactly what to search for)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
yes | pv --quiet --rate-limit 10
```

I used `yes` here to get a fast source of text; `pv` is an extremely useful tool for many reasons, but one of its features is a rate limiter.  You need to tell it to be quiet so it doesn't print its progress indicator.  The limit is in bytes per second.

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/526242/cat-file-to-terminal-at-particular-speed-of-lines-per-second

Comment: This is why we need the ability to mark as duplicate of questions on SuperUser.

Comment: @BenVoigt: yes, I would have used that ability here.  As it was, I just voted to close the question as it fits SU better anyway.

Comment: i understand your point, but this case for instance, thanks to people i had many new (and nicer) answers with very different approaches than on the previous question pointed by John Zwinck (only 1 answer, using perl). so i guess duplicate questions sometimes adds value due to new answering people...

Comment: @comte: I agree with you that new knowledge is good, but in this case we wound up with an awk solution which doesn't work properly on Mac OS X (as per my comment), and a Bash solution which spawns a new process for every line it prints!  This is not progress--both of the solutions in the answer you accepted are far worse than what we had before.  Not your fault--you didn't know any better.  :)

Comment: @John, regarding osx, tags for question where "linux" and "shell". regarding the accepted solution, yes i didn't know that it was so process consuming, i had a problem, and it was quickest answer and it worked so i accepted ! now with all comments regarding these methods, i unaccepted the answer, allowing future users to have the best answer.

Comment: @John, this question just earned a "Popular question" badge, seems we've got our answer regarding the off-topicness...

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=usleep -pe '$|=1;usleep(300000)'
#or
perl -pe 'select(undef,undef,undef,0.3)'
```

you can add the above as an shell function into your `~/.profile` e.g.

slowcat

```
slowcat() {
    perl -MTime::HiRes=usleep -pe '$|=1;usleep(300000)' "$@"
}
```

will accepts filenames and also input from pipes,

```
slowcat filenames....
command | slowcat
```

The following will produce output as an typical movie-computer screen or a connection like thru 300Baud modem...

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=usleep -ne '$|=1;while($c=getc(*stdin)){usleep(33000);print $c}'
```

Comment: +1 for `slowcat` - I love it! Can you do a `totallyexhausetedcat` too? :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell :) the `totallyexhausetedcat` is too easy. I made another one: `drunkcat() { perl -MTime::HiRes=usleep -ne '$|=1;while($c=getc(*stdin)){usleep(33000);print int(rand(10))%9?$c:chr(rand(26)+97)}' < "$1"; }` :)

Comment: Too funny! You should sell that - people are always looking for ways to make it look like they are typing commands in a Terminal when they are making their YouTube tutorial videos!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash


while read -r line; do 
   echo "$line"; # do whatever you want with line
   sleep 0.05

done < file
```

Comment: +1 for the simplest method :) /always use the `-r` for the `read` unless you want process escaped characters - edited/

Comment: Also, read [@CharlesDuffy 's coment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161285/how-to-make-a-cat-tac-stream-at-given-line-second-rate#comment41017336_26161785) why is better to use `printf`.

Comment: This is bad: it spawns a new `sleep` process for every line processed.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

```
 cat filename|awk  '{print $0 ; system("sleep 0.05")}'
```

Since according to most of the people above solution is dirty, I will suggest the following one liner:

```
while read line; do echo $line; sleep 0.05 ; done < filename
```

Comment: On my system (Mac OS X, bash), this results in an stream of output which cannot be canceled by Ctrl-C nor even Ctrl-\.  Nasty!

Comment: Not sure about Mac OS X. but this works perfecly on my Ubuntu's bash shell.

Comment: forking an new shell every 0.05 seconds is not the best idea...

Comment: `while read line; do echo $BASHPID; echo $line; sleep 0.05 ; done < filename` It prints same $BASHPID for every line

Comment: Does the above script runs in same shell ?

Comment: the `while read...` shell script is ok - but the `awk` forks new shell every 0.05 seconds... try it `system("sleep 0.05;echo $$")` ...

Comment: `echo $line` doesn't echo the exact line, but string-splits and glob-expands its contents. Use `echo "$line"` or, better, `printf '%s\n' "$line"` (which correctly handles, for instance, lines containing only `-e` or `-n`) instead.

Comment: and `-r` for the `read`... ;)

Comment: *nod* -- without `read -r`, lines containing `\n` -- two characters -- will be written back containing newlines (if you quote correctly) or spaces (if you don't); with `-r`, they'll correctly print with their two-character escape sequences.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy +10 if i could for the `-e|-n` comment!

Comment: @kobame: you're right, the Bash one-liner does fork a new process for every line of input printed (e.g. one per 0.05 seconds).  I tested it on Ubuntu 10.04 just to be certain.  RBH thinks $BASHPID proves the PID isn't changing, but it's not the Bash PID we care about, it's the thousands upon thousands allocated for `sleep`.